# When converting a code from unicode to ansi code we get ? as first character

Tags: c#

when converting a code from unicode to ansi code we get ? as first character .please help

```
byte[] ansibyte = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.Convert(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(865), unibytes);
```

it is working fine but it always displays the first character as ?

Comment: Code page 865 is not really ASCII. Try using System.Text.Encoding instead of System.Text.ASCIIEncoding. And try doing it in two stages, first from the byte array to a string, take a look at the string, and then convert from the string to code page 865..

Comment: unibytes is unicode file @SonerGönül

Comment: @RenniePet thank you i will try this System.Text.Encoding

Comment: @RenniePet even this gives the first character as ?                                                           string ansiConvert = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer).Trim();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, this isn't really an answer, but it's too difficult to write code in comments.

```
   class StackOverflow
   {
      byte[] unibytes;  // To be replaced by your data

      public void JustTesting()
      {
         string s;

         // Single-step these under the debugger, examine s after each attempt to see what works
         s = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(unibytes);
         s = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(unibytes);
         s = Encoding.BigEndianUnicode.GetString(unibytes);

         // Once you have the correct decoding, re-encode to code page 865
         byte[] asciiLikeByteArray = Encoding.GetEncoding(865).GetBytes(s);
      }
   }
```

What I meant by doing it in two stages is to first convert the Unicode byte array into a C# string, and examine the string. That's where the problem is, probably. Then, when the C# string is OK, convert that to the new byte array - it's unlikely that the problem is in that stage.

In the above code I suggest three possible conversions from "Unicode" to C# string. Unicode can exist in several different variations.

If none of those three possibilities work then it is probable that your byte array is not pure Unicode after all. Maybe it has a one-byte length prefix or something. You'll have to analyze that situation.